# Как сделать перемещение вверх страницы на jQuery?

Tags: jquery

А как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку с id="test" мы плавно перемещались в начало страницы, т.е. вверх? Помогите плиз, а то у самого не вышло. Слишком плохо jQuery знаю.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#test").bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 400);    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $.fn.scrollToTop=function(){
    $(this).hide().removeAttr("href");
    if($(window).scrollTop()!="0"){
        $(this).fadeIn("slow")
  }
  var scrollDiv=$(this);
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()=="0"){
    $(scrollDiv).fadeOut("slow")
    }else{
    $(scrollDiv).fadeIn("slow")
  }
  });
    $(this).click(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow")
    })
  }
});
$(function() {$("#test").scrollToTop();});
```

Более интересный вариант тем, что ссылка #test появляется при прокрутке страницы вниз.

Answer (score 0):

[Plugin ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Точнее, тут: [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

Comment: У меня не получилось. Я же написал..